# Vue 3 Geolocation computed property latitude and longitude always returning 0

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, vuejs3

i create a composable function to get current coordinates from geolocation and returned correctly, but when i acces in my script setup always returned 0

here is my composable useGeolocation.js

```js
import { onUnmounted, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
export function useGeolocation(){
    const kordinat = ref({ latitude: 0, longitude: 0 })
    const isSupported = 'navigator' in window && 'geolocation' in navigator

    let watcher = null
    onMounted(() => {
        if(isSupported)
        watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            position => (kordinat.value = position.coords)
        )
    })

    onUnmounted(()=> {
        if (watcher) navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcher)
    })
    return { kordinat, isSupported }
}
```

and how I use in my component

```html
<script setup>
import { useGeolocation } from '@/composables/useGeoLocation'
    const {kordinat} = useGeolocation()
    const posisiUser = computed(()=>({
        lat : kordinat.value.latitude,
        lng : kordinat.value.longitude
    }))
//...
</script>
```

in template i can display coordinates correctly with `<h2>Coords : {{posisiUser.lat}}, {{posisiUser.lng}}</h2>`

> Coords : -6.22592, 106.8302336

but when i log `console.log({p:posisiUser.value})` it returns `'{"p":{"lat":0,"lng":0}}'`

I need to be able access the correct coordinates for further usage. What is wrong?

here is sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-composition-api-script-setup-example-forked-ge5rkk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're [logging the value of the `computed` prop immediately](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-composition-api-script-setup-example-forked-ge5rkk?file=/src/App.vue:371-408), which is not yet updated:

```html
<script setup>
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useGeolocation } from "./composables/useGeoLocation";

const { kordinat } = useGeolocation();
const posisiUser = computed(() => ({
  lat: kordinat.value.latitude,
  lng: kordinat.value.longitude,
}));
console.log({ p: posisiUser.value }); // ❌ posisiUser not yet updated in useGeolocation()
</script>
```

If you want to log every change to the value, you can use a `watchEffect()`:

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log({ p: posisiUser.value });
})
```

To watch it only once, you can do:

```js
const unwatch = watchEffect(() => {
  unwatch();

  console.log({ p: posisiUser.value });
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-geolocation?file=src%2FApp.vue)